# How to mutate one column with `stringr` to select just some text between certain characters?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have some data in this format:

```
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   record id                                                           
#>    <int> <chr>                                                        
#> 1      1 "<a href=\"https://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/8379\">8379</a>"
#> 2      2 "<a href=\"https://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/8179\">8179</a>"
```

I would like to use `stringr` to be left with just the part of the string between ">" and "<".

So my desired output would be:

```
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   record id                                                           
#>    <int> <chr>                                                        
#> 1      1 "8379"
#> 2      2 "8179"
```

I have tried using `str_match`:

```
str_match(df$id, pattern = ">(....)<")
```

and the second column is what I'm after:

```
#>      [,1]     [,2]  
#> [1,] ">8379<" "8379"
#> [2,] ">8179<" "8179"
```

How do I know use it in say a `mutate` command to change a column in the dataframe?

Tidyverse solutions preferred, but open to all answers.

Code for data entry below.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-  tibble::tribble(
  ~record,                                                           ~id,
       1L, "<a href=\"https://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/8379\">8379</a>",
       2L, "<a href=\"https://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/8179\">8179</a>"
  )
df

str_match(df$id, pattern = ">(....)<")
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% muatate(id1 = str_match(df$id, pattern = ">(....)<")[,2])`

Comment: @NadPat That completely solves my problem.

Comment: Or `sub("^.*>(\\d+)<.*$", "\\1", df$id)`. But this is not a `stringr` solution.